# key/value shared preferences backup issue

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, backup, key-value

I'm using the default backup manager ,BackupAgentHelper for shared prefrences
can someone explain these errors:

1.W/PackageManager: checkUidPermission(): android.permission.BACKUP of 10129 is denied.

2.W/RestoreSession: No data available for this package; not restoring

what are the possible cases in which backup does not occur.

note:I have already added  android:allowBackup="true" attribute.

note2: i know the backup process doesn't create instant backup. i have tried waiting for 1 day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw many people facing problems in using the Key/value backup API provided by Google. In my case, due to following reasons my backup/restore functionality was not working.

1. when you request backup using  `BackupManager.dataChanged()` it doesn't backup your data instantly. I waited for 1 day,but my phone wasn't connected to Internet for long.so my backup was scheduled but never occurred.
2. while restoring data do remember that even after restore is finished, your shared preferences are not refreshed i.e `sharedPref.contains("mypref")` will return false.I don't know if its a bug or not, but when the activity is killed and restarted again shared preferences are set.
3. for Testing purpose you can view this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/testingbackup.html)  to have instant backups and restores
4. This backup API does not require any special permission. just

   `<application
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:backupAgent="CreateBackup"/>` is enough.